# Prove that x1 and x2 are eigen vectors of a 2x2 matrix if b is not equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra

A is a $2\times 2$ matrix=[(a, b)( c,d)] , show that if b ≠ 0 then x1 = [(-b, a-λ1)] and x2 = [(-b, a-λ2)] are eigenvectors that correspond to eigenvalues
λ1=1/2 (a+d)+√((a+d)^2+4bc)
λ2=1/2 (a+d)+√((a+d)^2+4bc)
[picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYd4m.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

To verify that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are eigenvectors of $A$, simply use the definition: If $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, $A x = \lambda x$.

So, calculate out $A x_i$ and see that its $\lambda_i x_i$.

Comment: Very helpful. I did exactly as you said and it worked just fine